# Spring datasource bean giving null pointer exception when it is used in controller

Tags: mysql, spring, nullpointerexception, datasource

I am using spring's BasicDataSource in my applicationContext.xml as following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd"
default-autowire="byType">

    <bean id="datasource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/school" />
        <property name="username" value="root" />
        <property name="password" value="" />
        <property name="initialSize" value="5" />
        <property name="maxActive" value="10" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

and when i use this bean in controller as follows:

```
package admin.controller;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import javax.inject.*;

@Controller
public class Welcome {

@Inject
BasicDataSource datasource;

private static final String WELCOME_PAGE = "welcome";

@RequestMapping("/")
public String welcome(ModelMap model){

    Connection con=null;
    PreparedStatement stmt =null;
    String testQuery = "INSERT INTO ADMIN(ID,USER_NAME,PASSWORD,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?)";
    try {
        con = datasource.getConnection();
        stmt = con.prepareStatement(testQuery);

        stmt.setInt(1, 4);
        stmt.setString(2, "ij");
        stmt.setString(3, "kl");
        stmt.setString(4, "mn");
        stmt.setString(5, "op");

        stmt.execute();

        //con.commit();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
    finally{
            try {
                if(con!=null)
                    con.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
    }
    return WELCOME_PAGE;
}   
}
```

then it gives me a nullpointer exception at line: datasource.getConnection();

connection details are 100% correct because when i create a new instance of BasicDatasource inside the controller and add details using its setter methods(eg: datasource.setDriverClassName etc.) then it connects to the database and execute the query without any problem. but when i want to use the bean from application context then it is giving me a null pointer exception.

Answer (score 0):

I've not got to the reason why I am having null pointer exception. but I am sure that I am doing mistake somewhere in binding. because when i remove the @Inject and implement a setter method for data source then i am not getting any other exception. And transaction completes successfully. please let me know if you can point out the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I've met another interesting fact that when i replace @Inject with @Autowired then it works fine and i don't have to write a setter method. But if I am using @Inject then i have to write a setter method to get it work. It sounds weird but seems true in my case.